# Problem with the double execution of event on JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input:text that i used to modify a table but i don't understand why the function execute 2 times when i press enter.
I try everything to stop the double execution and nothing.
This is the code of the JS:

```
$("#mdfTbl").unbind('keyup');

    $("#mdfTbl").keyup(function(event){
        if (event.keyCode == 13 && getData(this)!=''){
            if ($(this).parent().attr('id').split('.')[1].split('_')[1] == '0'){//This means if the position is 0 the position is in the id the number before the _td
                $("#attrTbl").attr('col', '0');
                father = $(this).parent();//Searching the father.
                $("body").append($(this));
                $(this).hide();
                if (exist(getData("attrTbl"), getData($(this))) == false){
                    //If theres no duplicate...
                    td = document.createElement('TD');//Creating the new TD
                    $(td).attr('id', $("#tbody1").children().length+'.td_1');//Adding the ID.
                    $(father).parent().append(td);//Appending the td to the grand father AKA: the body of the table.
                    $(father).append(getData($(this).attr('id')));//Appendding the data.
                    $(td).append(this);//Appending the modifier to the new TD
                    $(this).attr('value', '');//Cleaning
                    $(this).focus();//Focus again.
                    $(this).show();
                }else{
                    father.append(this);
                    $(this).show();
                }
            }else{
                var newCont = parseInt($("#tbody1").children().length)+1;
                //getting the td that will store the data.
                var father = $(this).parent();
                //Appending the data to the TD.
                $(father).append(getData(this));
                //This going to be the next td  
                var td = document.createElement('TD');
                $(td).attr('id', (newCont)+'_td.0');
                $(td).append(this);
                var tr = document.createElement('TR');
                $("#tbody1").append(tr);
                $(tr).attr('id', (newCont)+'_tr');
                $(tr).append(td);
                $(this).attr('value', '');//Cleaning
                $(this).show();
                $(this).focus();//Focus again.

            }
        }
    });
```

This is the HTML code:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <link href="http://dev.karinapp.com/modules/appgen/css/batute.css" id="css_batute_4" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="http://dev.karinapp.com/modules/batute/css/main.css" id="css_batute_22" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><script id="script0" src="http://dev.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script id="script1" src="http://dev.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script id="script2" src="http://dev.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
         <script id="script3" src="http://dev.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.button.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
         <script id="script4" src="/modules/general/scripts/general.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
         <link href="http://dev.karinapp.com/modules/general/css/karinapp-style/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css" id="link4" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
         <script id="script5" src="/modules/appgen/scripts/batute.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
         <script id="script6">function __init__(){

           mainBt();
         }</script>
         <script id="pdloadScr" src="/modules/general/scripts/loadPage.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script><script id="pdLoader" type="text/javascript">window.onload = function(){postLoad();
__init__();}</script><script id="script9" src="/modules/general/scripts/Catcher.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>

  </head>
  <body id="body" key="ca6161395761c5f830dc17d47b553183af77430e">
      <div father="body" id="btcreator" style="display: block; ">
            <!--Comment-->

            <label father="@btcreator" id="fncNm_lbl"><!--empty-->              Name:
            </label>
            <label father="@btcreator" id="fatherlbl"><!--empty-->Father:
            </label>
            <input father="@btcreator" id="fncnm" type="text">
            <select father="@btcreator" id="fatherbt"><!--Comment--><option father="@fatherbt" id="fatherbt_Opt0" name="fatherbt_Opt0" value="none">No father</option></select>

            <button father="@btcreator" id="createBt" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text"><!--empty-->Create</span></button>
                    <select father="@btcreator" id="fncName"><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt0" name="fncName_Opt0" value="default">Select one...</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt1" name="fncName_Opt1" value="oper">Operation</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt2" name="fncName_Opt2" value="dirls">List of directories</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt3" name="fncName_Opt3" value="opnfl">Open File</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt4" name="fncName_Opt4" value="delete">Delete File</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt5" name="fncName_Opt5" value="compare">Compare</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt6" name="fncName_Opt6" value="cp">Copy</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt7" name="fncName_Opt7" value="get">Get</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt8" name="fncName_Opt8" value="switch">Switch(If-Else)</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt9" name="fncName_Opt9" value="upload">Upload</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt10" name="fncName_Opt10" value="modify">Modify(Elements)</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt11" name="fncName_Opt11" value="create">Create(Elements)</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt12" name="fncName_Opt12" value="find">Select(SQL)</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt13" name="fncName_Opt13" value="insert">Insert(SQL)</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt14" name="fncName_Opt14" value="update">Update(SQL)</option></select>
            <button father="@btcreator" id="addRpl" value="Add Reply"><!--empty-->Add Reply</button><label father="@btcreator" id="fncNameLbl"><!--empty-->Function:</label>

        <label father="@btcreator" for="dtype" id="dTypelbl">Data-Type:</label><select father="@btcreator" id="dtype"><!--Comment--><option father="@dtype" id="dtype_Opt0" name="dtype_Opt0" value="data">Data</option><option father="@dtype" id="dtype_Opt1" name="dtype_Opt1" value="int">Integer</option><option father="@dtype" id="dtype_Opt2" name="dtype_Opt2" value="float">Float</option><option father="@dtype" id="dtype_Opt3" name="dtype_Opt3" value="str">String</option><option father="@dtype" id="dtype_Opt4" name="dtype_Opt4" value="list">Array/List</option></select><button father="@btcreator" id="goto">Go to object...</button><button father="@btcreator" id="frmSrc">Add from source</button><button father="@btcreator" id="frmbt">Add from batute</button><button father="@btcreator" id="addsttc">Add static</button><button father="@btcreator" id="prevsb" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title=""><span class="ui-button-text"><!--Comment--></span><span class="ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-w"></span></button><button father="@btcreator" id="gtson" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title=""><span class="ui-button-text"><!--Comment--></span><span class="ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s"></span></button><button father="@btcreator" id="nxtsb" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title=""><span class="ui-button-text"><!--Comment--></span><span class="ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e"></span></button><button father="@btcreator" id="fthsb" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title=""><span class="ui-button-text"><!--Comment--></span><span class="ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n"></span></button><button father="@btcreator" id="svBt" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Save object</span></button><div father="@btcreator" id="btattr"><!--Comment-->

<table border="1" father="btattr" id="attrTbl" width="100%" col="0">
  <thead father="@attrTbl" id="thead1">
    <tr>
      <th>Property</th><th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody father="@attrTbl" id="tbody1">
    <tr id="tbody0">
      <td id="tbody.tr_0">sdfasdfasdf</td>
      <td id="1.td_1">asdfasdfasdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2_tr">
      <td id="2_td.0">adsfasdfsadf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3_tr">
      <td id="3_td.0"><input id="mdfTbl" style="width: 180px; display: inline-block; " type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <colgroup>
    <col father="@attrTbl" id="col0" width="50%">
    <col father="@attrTbl" id="col1" width="50%">
  </colgroup>
</table>
</div></div>

<button father="body" id="showhid" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="

            " style="left: 502px; "><span class="ui-button-text">
                <!--Comment-->
            </span><span class="ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e"></span></button></body></html>
```

Comment: Looks me as if you've forgotten `var` in a couple places.

Comment: Also, if you're going to post code, it would be courteous to ensure that it can be read easily by people trying to help you.

Comment: Labels with attributes 'father'?? I've never seen that before. Anybody?

Comment: I use the father attribute in another script.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning `false` from the "keyup" handler when you detect that the user has pressed the "Enter" key.